# Nuxt.js + Socket.io

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I was looking into how to use socket.io with Nuxt and came across this: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/master/examples/with-sockets

Can someone explain why the `io` module is creating a socketio server? All the socketio configuration is also being done in server.js already so isn’t that part of the `io` module redundant?

Comment: i have wrote an blog post about it https://blogxon.com/articles/nuxt-with-socket-io

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches. The `server.js` is an example of using Nuxt programmatically with WebSockets together. When using `nuxt.config.js` with the `io` module, it works "standalone".

Quoted from [me here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3001)

The description also available in the `dev` branch ([here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/examples/with-sockets/))